# Develop React-Native application behind proxy

Tags: javascript, react-native, proxy

I'm developing an application with React-Native, but I have a problem with the proxy: I set Node with "npm config proxy / https-proxy ..." and I can install the application without problems, but when Metro Bundler starts for debugging and downloading dependencies, I have this "No Bundle URL present" screen (when I work in tethering this thing does not happen and everything works correctly). How do I solve it? What should I set?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:"npm config set https-proxy http://proxyHostName:port"(npm config set https-proxy http://172.58.37.51:8080")
or "npm config set proxy http://proxyHostName:port"

Comment: I did it but it's the same